# Return Key Text Field? - iPhone SDK

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I've been searching the web for a really long time, and I can't get this to work. On my text field I have, when I click on it and then press done or return it won't go away. I've done all the steps for every single tutorial but I still can't get it to work. I'm on firmware 3.1.2, but anyway here is the code in my ViewController.m:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    blah.delegate = self;
    blah.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;

}

- (BOOL)blahShouldReturn:(UITextField *)blah{

    [blah resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}
```

viewcontroller.h:

```
@interface BlahViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate> {
    IBOutlet UITextField *blah;

}
```

These are just cut outs from the files. Anyway can anyone help me? I can't get rid of the keyboard when I click on it...

Thanks,

Kevin

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm confused. Are you actually expecting a method called `blahShouldReturn:` to get called when you press the Return button? If you want to use the `textFieldShouldReturn:` delegate method, it has to be called `textFieldShouldReturn:`. You can use the `UITextField` parameter supplied with that method to determine which text field is sending the message. For example:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
    if (textField == blah) {
        [textField resignFirstResponder];
    } else if (textField == someOtherTextField) {
        // Do something else
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

.m file:

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad {

 [super viewDidLoad];

 blah.delegate = self;
 blah.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;

 //Call hideKeyboard action when done button is clicked
 [blah addTarget:self action:@selector(hideKeyboard) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingDidEndOnExit];

 }

 //Custom hide keyboard action
 - (void)hideKeyboard {

 [blah resignFirstResponder];

 }
```

.h file:

```
 //Dont need delegate for this method of hiding keyboard!
 @interface BlahViewController : UIViewController {
 IBOutlet UITextField *blah;

 }

 - (void)hideKeyboard;

 @end
```